# Disable copy action form other app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipasteboard

How can i do this:

1. disable user can copy info in my app to other app.
2. when user copy info in other app, it can not paste into my app.
3. in my app, user can copy and paste info normaly.

I know UIPasteboard has systemwide general pasteboard and named pasteboards, but the UITextView and UITextField have it's default pasteboard action.

Comment: My problem may can be described as: how to make the systemwide general pasteboard worked as a named pasteboards

Answer (score 1):

1. You can clear the `UIPasteboard` on your `applicationDidEnterBackground` (set an empty string will do) :)
2. Make a bool global variable for copy action (do it before or after `setString`), disable it if the user quit using the app on `applicationDidEnterBackground`, if the variable is `true` then allow pasting

Comment: finally use method swizzle, replace general pasteboard with named pasteboard.